# transferring via pipeline

Tags: scripting, csh, tcsh

I need to transfer data via pipe and also transfer file with this data, can I do something like this inside the script?

```
cat ${1} | ./helper ${1}
```

and what is the difference if I write

```
cat ${1} | ./helper < ${1}
```

Comment: I assume you mean in a shell script. I don't understand, what's wrong with writing the very syntax you used?

Comment: yes shell script, but what is the difference between first case and second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"<" adds the file content to your scripts stdin

pipe also redirects the output for stdin of the ./helper script

you could eithe do `cat ${1} | ./helper`
or `./helper < ${1}` assuming ${1} is a filename and in helper script access it from /dev/stdin